# Datatables with HTML UI in Shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I'm not well-versed with javascript or jQuery and I am (therefore?) struggling with integrating datatables with an HTML UI in Shiny. All the examples I can find seem to work with `ui.r` and not with an HTML UI.

Any example or advice on how to do this?

( I've been pointed to the excellent app at http://emoteer.com/ but I'm unable to find out how it works )

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific as to what problem you are encountering.  There are a variety of useful resources: [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html), [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html), and [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/).

Comment: The problem I'm facing is exactly as I've mentioned, and all the links you've sent also indicate, that most examples on the net use the `ui.r` way of building the UI. I'm trying to build an HTML UI instead and I do not know how to feed a `datatables` to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate or point to sources or examples that explain what you mean by `HTML UI`?  The pages generated by a `ui.r` + `shiny.r` will be `HTML` -- perhaps you mean `htmlwidgets` which can be leveraged in an RMarkdown document.

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this for the `index.html`

```
<html>    
<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/> 
  <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/dataTables.extra.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>     
<body>
  <h1>HTML UI</h1>
  <div id="table" class="shiny-datatable-output"></div>
</body>    
</html>
```

And in the `server.R`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

        output$table <- renderDataTable({iris})

})
```

You will need to put the javascript, css and images in the `www` directory where the `index.html` is.

---

Edit on 13th March -

If you copy the `C:\Users\<username>Documents\R\win-library\3.1\shiny\www\shared` folder to the `www` folder inside which the `index.html` file is place, then the following should take care of it.

```
<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/> 

  <link href="shared/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="shared/datatables/css/dataTables.extra.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, @NicE! I've added a for-dummies version below your answer as some of the folder paths you've listed seem to be different than mine.

If it doesn't merit a separate question, could you please tell me why the `dataTableOutput` isn't needed at all? I tried something similar as your code, I kept getting a warning.